# angular template cache doesn't work when template key contains file extension

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-template, angular-templatecache

Template cache fails for me for some reason, when I do this:

```
angular.module('myApp').run([
    '$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('test.html', 'content');
    }
]);
```

and then when using routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when("/my/url", {
              templateUrl: 'test.html'
          })
```

However, if I change my key from "test.html" to just "test", it works. For some reason, it fails soon as I add the file extension to the key.

Comment: Define *"fails"*. Perhaps you have another template named `test.html`. Try something unique, like `test1234.html`

Comment: By fails, I mean it doesn't pull the template from the cache, and goes against the server. I tried `test1234.html` and got the same result.

Comment: Ah, so you can see a network request being made for `test.html`? Any chance you can try to replicate the problem in a Plunker example? Do you have any customisation / configuration of `$templateCache` or `$cacheFactory`?

Comment: Looking in to other instances like this, I'm seeing suggestions to populate the `$templateCache` in a separate module (eg `'myApp.templates'`) and make it a dependency of your main module (`'myApp'`). Give that a try

Comment: I completely forgot I had an interceptor adding a query param to my request (for cache busting), which I overlooked when looking at the network call. No issues here (apart from me missing a simple thing :/ ). Thanks nonetheless for your suggestions!